# In PHP MVC, How to show external css, js and image files?

Tags: php, .htaccess, model-view-controller

In PHP MVC, How to show external css, js and image files?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I could not show any external files.

Answer (score 0):

The code above matches the `${REQUEST_URI}`, e.g. matches at all uris, where you probably want to match the requested filename `${REQUEST_FILENAME}`

Moreover, the code above also matches non existent symlinks ("`!-l`") and non existent directories ("`!-d`").

Probably only matching non-existent filenames would work perfectly:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Now, only requested filenames that don't physically exist on in the folder index.php resides in will be aliased to index.php.

For speed purposes, or if Apache rejects to display your static css and such you can disable the RewriteEngine on a given directory, for example:

```
<Directory "path/to/public_html">
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1
</Directory>
<Directory "path/to/public_html/static">
  RewriteEngine Off
</Directory>
```

The order of the directories might be the other way around if the example above doesn't work. Also make sure to add this to your .htaccess file or in your `<VirtualHost>`-tag.